# C++ Trouble declaring function prototype within header file

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I have been given the following code to work with within a MatrixTest.cpp function:

```
Matrix matrix = Matrix::Zeros(2,4)
```

The aim is to "create a 2x4 matrix of zeros with the static Zeros" and I need to be able to add something to the header file "Matrix.h" which allows "MatrixTest.cpp" to compile for the line of code above.  This is the code in my header file so far:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H_
#define MATRIX_H_

class Matrix {
protected:
    // These are the only member variables allowed!
    int noOfRows;
    int noOfColumns;
    double *data;

    int GetIndex (const int rowIdx, const int columnIdx) const;

public:
    Matrix (const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols);
    Matrix (const Matrix& input);
    Matrix& operator= (const Matrix& rhs);
    ~Matrix ();

    Matrix Zeros(const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols);
};

#endif /* MATRIX_H_ */
```

This gives the error in my .cpp file that I cannot call member function Matrix Matrix::Zeros(int, int) without object.  But surely Zeros is my object and my Matrix class is my type?

If I change my code in the header file to the following:

```
static Zeros(const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols);
```

Then I get an error within my .h file saying "forbids declaration of 'Zeros' with no type and an error within my .cpp file saying "conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Matrix' requested"

I'm confused since I would've thought that my type is Matrix as it appears underneath the class Matrix and that since Matrix::Zeros(2,4) follows the constructor Matrix(const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols) then there wouldn't be a conversion issue from 'int' to non-scalar type.

Can anybody help with this as I seem to be going back and forth between these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the function should be

```
static Matrix Zeros(const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols);
```

The `static` keyword is *not* the return type, `Matrix` is. Rather the `static` keyword states that you do not need an instance of a `Matrix` to call the method, instead you can call it as

```
Matrix matrix = Matrix::Zeros(2,4)
```

To be clear, if you did *not* use the word `static` then you would have to do something like

```
Matrix a{};
Matrix matrix = a.Zeros(2,4);
```

but you can see that the `Zeros` method doesn't depend on the state of `a` so it would make sense for the method to be `static` instead.

Comment: His acceptance of your answer definitely seems to indicate that I just read too much into it. Oh well

Comment: @R_Kapp No worries :) Better to be safe than sorry, especially in programming where it pays to be as specific and accurate as possible.

Comment: Yeah thanks!  The explanation of static helped my understanding as I was thinking it might have been a choice of either static or Matrix, but it worked using both

Answer (score 0):

Since `static` is not a return type here, and your function is returning a `Matrix`, that would be your return type.

Changing your function signature to 
`static Matrix Zeros(const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols);` should do the trick.